# Shimano chainring / crankset compatibility

Tags: shimano, crankset

I discovered a Shimano FC-2300 Crankset (175-mm 52/42/30T 8 Speed) for $62 on Amazon - is this compatible to replace my old FC 3301/3304?

The longer story is I need to replace my Shimano chain (CS-HG50) / middle chainring from an SG 52-42-30 set (and I expect rear cassette too?) after 5 yrs of a modest commute on my 8 speed flat bar bike.
Can anyone recommend an online seller of suitable replacement parts compatible with the Sora FC 3301/3304?  My local shop in Perth Australia proposes to sell me a new bike, but I'd rather repair to safe and functional level - I won't be winning any races on this unit:)
I'm new at the repair work and tho' I've got a chain tool, it appears I'll also need to get special tools (crank extractor?) to get at the chainrings?  Do I also need special tools for to replace the rear cartridge?
Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes you could replace your crank set with the FC-2303 but you would have to change your bottom bracket also. Look up the Shimano tech docs for these cranksets, all the information you need is there as well as the steps you take to change the bottom bracket.

The triple ring crankset is the FC-3304 with a 45mm chain line using a 118mm octalink bottom bracket.

The FC-2303 is the triple ring crankset which also has a 45mm chain line but uses a 113mm square taper bottom bracket.

So alongside the **crank extractor** you will need a **bottom bracket tool**. I got a crank extractor and a BB tool for about $10 NZD each. To change a rear cassette you will need a **lock ring nut** which will fit your rear cassette.

I shop at [Chain Reaction Cycles](http://chainreactioncycles.com) which ships from the UK and is cheap and reliable with fast shipping. They sell components and tools at good rates with ok shipping rates.

Comment: Thank you DWGKNZ!
Is there is a different triple ring crankset with a 45mm chain line and a 118mm octalink BB on the market that would save me changing the BB?  Or would you recommend changing the BB anyway?

Comment: I had to replace my crankset recently and went through a similar thing. I didn't find anywhere online that gave a reference on cranksets, BBs and chain lines so it's just about leg work to find one. I had to change my BB, the one I fitted wasn't expensive and I found the job resonably simple. IMHO, if the BB was cheap I'd say replace it while you had the crank off as it will wear out one day and it's 5 years old.